# Properties instantiating other properties

Tags: properties

Hi im thinking about instantiation and properties and whether properties can instantiate other properties. Is it true that properties can instantiate other ones? Are there any good examples of it?
Thanks

Comment: Look up second-order properties or second-order logic

Comment: See [Second-order and Higher-order Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/#Intr)

Comment: For Frege, *existence* is a second order property.

Comment: Think about it what does *instantiate a property* really mean?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

Consider a thermometer based on red-dyed alcohol. You must construct it with some amount of liquid. This amount is a property. You must also construct it with some ratio between water and dye and alcohol. This ratio produces the expansion properties of the liquid with temperature. These properties are, ta-da!, properties. So the quantity of liquid and the ratio of components produces (instantiates) the volume at different temperatures, which are still more properties.

So, the combination of these properties, and the volume of the glass components of the thermometer, produce the property that a temperature of 30°C will have a liquid height of one value (a property) and a temperature of 10°C will have a different height of liquid (another property).